# svn to git - Import only trunk with full history

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am currently migrating my WordPress Plugins from SVN to git using `git-svn` by issuing the following commands

```
git svn clone -r12345 -A AUTHORS_FILE --no-minimize-url --username=SVN_USERNAME http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/posts-by-tag
git svn fetch
```

It is working, but the problem is that it is very slow because the repo is huge and I have lot of tags. `git-svn` tries to retrieve all the tags and it is taking very long (around 3-4 hours for 15-20 tags)

I don't need the tags and I am not going to commit back to svn using `git-svn`. So I am trying to see if it would possible to retrieve only the trunk (leaving the tags and branches) but with full history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply specify `/trunk` as the top-level directory:

```
git svn clone -r12345 -A AUTHORS_FILE --no-minimize-url --username=SVN_USERNAME \
  http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/posts-by-tag/trunk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the --ignore-paths parameter as documented [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html)